# Make block level element clickable with XHTML 1.0

Tags: html, xhtml, doctype

I'm working on a site that uses the XHTML 1.0 transitional DOCTYPE. Therefore, as far as I understand it, its up to the browser to decide how to treat newer features.

I have a need to wrap a block level element in a link to make the whole thing clickable. However, I know this technically shouldn't be allowed before HTML5. The major browsers seem to handle it fine though.

My questions is: to be guaranteed this will work consistently in all browsers, should I do this with JS rather than wrap the div in an anchor and trust the browser to treat it in the modern way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a choice of a doctype string has nothing to do with support to HTML5 features. Either a browser supports those features, or it does not.

The doctype string affects the mode of the browser, [quirks mode](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html) vs. standards mode. But the mode mainly affects interpretation of CSS. Although some HTML issues are affected, too, the XHTML 1.0 doctypes *when specified literally as per XHTML 1.0 recommendation*, trigger standards mode just as the HTML5 doctype does.

Besides, wrapping a block element inside an `a` element works in quirks mode, too. It is a browser tradition to ignore old HTML rules on what may or may not be included in an `a` element; HTML5 just makes this a rule.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So it's a gamble but a calculated gamble to wrap the divs in anchors because we know most browsers will accept it.